# Get character name in word VBA

Tags: vba, vb6

Here i am want to get the character names in word by using VBA. For example

- a-> Latin Small Letter A
- A-> Latin Capital Letter A

**Note:**

`ASC()` and  `ASCW()` is used to get character values `(eg: asc("a") = 97)`,  like as is there is any method to get the character name or else?

[image]

Comment: I am get those character names from charmap.

Answer (score 3):

[Here you go.](http://www.ascii-code.com/)

With this table, you can take each character one at a time, and compare it to the table I listed. So, if you had an **å**, then using **ASC(å)** you'd get **229**, then do a lookup on your table and you'll get "***Latin small letter a with ring above***".

Repeat with each letter.

Comment: Ya correct Mr.Tom, but i am want to get the name of character by read the document content (character) and find the corresponding character name. like reading the character and getting those ascii value using ASC().

Comment: @thir There is no built-in function for this. You need to create a look-up table in your code (like the ones Tom has linked to) and write your own retrieval function.

Comment: Tom, both your comment and mine should probably be edited into your answer. That would make it much more helpful (and worthy of an upvote) than a snarky comment about how Google is useful to find answers to questions, even though I agree.

Comment: Edited. Took your suggestion and elaborated the answer.

Comment: Ya Thank you Mr.Tom And Mr.Cody